# ExpressJS POST cannot log body

Tags: json, node.js, express

After a lot of fiddling with upgrading versions and the different middleware/ways of using a body parser, I am still stuck.

I have an Iphone app which POSTs 2 things (2 separate things). First is an image, which works.
Second is a json object which i try to put into mongodb.

No matter what i do, i can't seem to log the contents of the request.

```
var express = require('express');
var logger = require('morgan');
var fs = require('fs');
var json = require('express-json');
var path = require('path');
var errorHandler = require('errorhandler');
MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient,
Server = require('mongodb').Server,
CollectionDriver = require('./collectionDriver').CollectionDriver;
FileDriver = require('./fileDriver').FileDriver;
```

...

```
app.use(json());
//app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

...

```
app.post('/:collection', function(req, res) {
  console.warn(req.body.poi.toString());
  var object = req.body;
  var collection = req.params.collection;
  console.warn("Post: " + req.toString());
  collectionDriver.save(collection, object, function(err,docs) {
      if (err) { res.send(400, err); } 
      else { res.send(201, docs); }
  });
});
```

I've tried logging (log, warn) req.body, req, etc. to no avail.
i'm using express-json and NOT url encoding, don't think need it.

morgan ouputs the following when i post

```
POST /pois 200 15.983 ms - 63
```

and nothing else!

Comment: If you insert `console.dir(req.headers['content-type']);` into your route, what does it show in the console?

Comment: huh, that worked! *looking at docs for console.dir*

Comment: sry, didnt really answer your question... it was 'application/json'

Comment: console.dir(typeof(req.body)); gives "undefined"

Comment: did you try commenting out `app.use(json());` and using `app.use(bodyParser.json());` instead?

Comment: AHHHH its working!!!!! My experience with NodeJS and ExpressJS has been good so far other than the body parsing middleware which has changed a bunch in the various versions!

Answer (score 1):

It apparently cannot do it, as stated in this closed issue https://github.com/expressjs/morgan/issues/16 
`morgan` is not intended for this kind of work. Try and use Winston instead, or simply `console.log`

Answer (score 0):

This does it for me:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
app.use(express.json())

var morgan = require('morgan')

morgan.token('response-body', (req, res) => {return JSON.stringify(req.body)});  // define 'response-body' token using JSON.stringify

app.use(morgan(':method :url :response-time :response-body')) //include newly defined ':response-body' token

app.post(/....)
```